# Laravel user model not being process in JSON response

Tags: json, laravel, response

I have a Laravel 5.8 API where the JSON response for a user collection works as expected but fails for a model.

```php
namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

trait ApiResponder
{
    private function successResponse($data, $code)
    {
        return response()->json($data, $code);
    }

    protected function errorResponse($message, $code)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => $message, 'code' => $code], $code);
    }

    protected function showAll(Collection $collection, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $collection], $code);
    }

    protected function showOne(Model $model, $code = 200)
    {
        return $this->successResponse(['data' => $model], $code);
    }
}
```

Below are the controller methods calling for the response.

```php
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return $this->showAll($users);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $rules = [
        'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
        'password' => 'min:6|confirmed'
    ];

    if ($request->has('name')) {
        $user->name = $request->name;
    }

    if ($request->has('email') && $user->email != $request->email) {
        $user->verififed = User::UNVERIFIED_USER;
        $user->verififcation_token = User::generateVerificationCode();
        $user->email = $request->email;
    }

    if ($request->has('password')) {
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    }

    if (!$user->isDirty()) {
        return $this->errorResponse('You need to specify a change to update', 422);
    }

    $user->save();

    $this->showOne($user);
}
```

The index method handle as a collection works perfectly, but the update method using the model returns empty (no content at all). I have confirmed that the `$data` variable does contain the model information as expected as I can print a JSON encode that displays the result I want. It's just not working in `response()->json()` for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Very complex code for what it actually does.

Here you have the problem, needless to say to render the response, you need a return.

```
    $user->save();

    $this->showOne($user);
}
```

should be:

```
    $user->save();

    return $this->showOne($user);
}
```

Bonus: I would look into response transformation for future references see [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) or [Fractal](https://fractal.thephpleague.com/). Instead of doing to much if logic, you can use [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) to validate the input.

Comment: Thank you for your response, frustrating when its something simple. I have been following a tutorial on udemy to set up this API and try and use the best resources, but hey ho. Thanks for your help

Comment: If it help you solve it please mark it as an answer, so it can help people getting into this post later on.